Enable permission for dictation in code on ios
In iOS when the keyboard is presented for a text input there is a button for access to dictation.
the first time you press this button in the app a permissions alert will show.
this alert will make the keyboard disappear which causes me drama because it calls some logic to reorganise my screen which causes the alert to disappear so the user never gets a chance to enable it.
Is there a way I can force the app to show this alert on view did appear so I dont end up in the loop ?
regards Christian Stœr Andersen.
